# Background-image completely covering parallax background-image

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas, parallax

I have a background parallax image that I want to conform to another .png on top of it. To achieve this in its current state, I would have to change the background-size on the .parallaxLetters component to contain, not cover. Obviously when I do this though, the parallax effect breaks. Any workarounds?  For example:

[At 100% Zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZuWL.jpg)

[At 75% Zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cve1W.jpg)

***CSS:***

```
.Study 
{
    overflow-y: hidden ! important;
    overflow-x: hidden ! important;
    height: 1094px; 
    background-image: url("FlashPacks/studyB.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px; 
}

.parallaxLetters 
{
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("FlashPacks/swirl5.png");

    /* Set a specific height */

    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
    overflow-y: hidden ! important;
    overflow-x: hidden ! important;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

***HTML:***

```
<!-- Middle Text -->
<div class="parallaxLetters">
    <div class="Study">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this something you are looking for? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XzzVKv

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd No, I want a .png on the top to cover an image of the exact same size completely, no matter what the browser zoom is at. This is so only the letters cut out of the top .png, show the parallax effect behind it.

Comment: Here is an example, it is fine on zoom out, but it overflows the top on zoom in: https://i.imgur.com/QQSds9B.gifv